# Plotting ODE solutions with two parameters

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a system of two first-order ODEs with two parameters, a and b and I'm trying to plot the solution curve in the X-Y plane at a given initial condition for various parameter values. Can someone give me a simple way of doing this? I've been experimenting with ParametricNDSolve but I'm new to Mathematica and I think I'm using it incorrectly. Any resources or information would be appreciated.

Comment: use Manipulate, make sliders for the parameters, and do DSolve inside Manipulate and plot the solution(s).

Comment: There are examples in the documentation for `ParametricNDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolveValue`.  If you showed how you're using it, someone might be able to point out any mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

```
eq = {  x'[t] Sin[y[ t]] + x[t] y'[t] a == 1, y'[t] Cos[x[t]] - y[t] x'[t] b == 1}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0,  1}, {a, b}]

Manipulate[ ParametricPlot[{x[a, b][t], y[a, b][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1},  AspectRatio -> 1], 
           {a, 0.5, 1}, {b, 0.5, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]